# How to Calculate sales growth?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I want to get total monthly sales growth from three (3) tables. Can someone show me how to do it?

**Table1**

| Month | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Sep 2023 | 2.00 |
| Oct 2023 | 3.00 |
| Oct 2023 | 1.00 |

**Table2**

| Month | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Sep 2023 | 1.00 |
| Oct 2023 | 2.00 |
| Oct 2023 | 2.00 |

**Table3**

| Month | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Sep 2023 | 5.00 |
| Oct 2023 | 2.00 |
| Oct 2023 | 1.00 |

This is what l have tried

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT OrderDate, Amount FROM Table1 
    UNION ALL 
SELECT OrderDate, Amount FROM Table2 
    UNION ALL SELECT OrderDate, Amount FROM Table3)
SELECT 
    Datepart(Month, OrderDate) as 
    monthly_sales, Sum(Amount) As monthly_sales FROM  CTE Group by Datepart(Month, OrderDate),
CTE2 AS (SELECT *,  lag(monthly_sales) over (order by Month ) as prev_month_sales FROM CTE ), 
CTE3 AS (SELECT     *,  100*(monthly_sales - prev_month_sales)/(prev_month_sales) as sales_growth FROM CTE2)
SELECT * from CTE3
```

Expected output.

**Sales growth **

| Month | monthly_sales | prev_month_sales | sales_growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sep 2023 | 8.00 | 0 | 0 |
| Oct 2023 | 7.00 | 8.0 | 12.52 |
| Oct 2023 | 4.00 | 7.0 | -42.86 |

Comment: You forgot to include what the problem is with your current query. Why does your query use the same alias `monthly_sales` for multiple columns? Why is your query using pre-ansi comma-delimited joins? If `cte3` is your final result why do you even define it just to select * from it?

Comment: You already [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77430356/2029983); don't delete and repost questions. If you need to improve your question, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77430356/edit) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can contain all data in 1 CTE and then join with lagged data. Here is my solution:

```
-- Create the tables
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    [Month] date,
    Amount decimal(18, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    [Month] date,
    Amount decimal(18, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE Table3 (
    [Month] date,
    Amount decimal(18, 2)
);

-- Insert data into the tables
INSERT INTO Table1 ([Month], Amount)
VALUES
    ('2023-09-01', 2.00),
    ('2023-10-01', 3.00),
    ('2023-10-01', 1.00);

INSERT INTO Table2 ([Month], Amount)
VALUES
    ('2023-09-01', 1.00),
    ('2023-10-01', 2.00),
    ('2023-10-01', 2.00);

INSERT INTO Table3 ([Month], Amount)
VALUES
    ('2023-09-01', 5.00),
    ('2023-10-01', 2.00),
    ('2023-10-01', 1.00);

-- Calculate sales growth
WITH CombinedData AS (
    SELECT [Month], SUM(Amount) AS monthly_sales
    FROM (
        SELECT [Month], Amount FROM Table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Month], Amount FROM Table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Month], Amount FROM Table3
    ) AS Combined
    GROUP BY [Month]
),
SalesGrowth AS (
    SELECT
        FORMAT([Month], 'MMM yyyy') [Month],
        monthly_sales,
        LAG(monthly_sales, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY  [Month]) AS prev_month_sales,
        CASE
            WHEN LAG(monthly_sales, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Month]) = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE (monthly_sales - LAG(monthly_sales, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY  [Month])) * 100.0 / LAG(monthly_sales, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Month])
        END AS sales_growth
    FROM CombinedData
)
SELECT [Month], monthly_sales, prev_month_sales, sales_growth
FROM SalesGrowth;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table3
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Here is [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/4qWgDlK6)

NB: I create `sales_growth` on percentage (multiplied by 100). You can change to make it suitable to your requirement